# 403 access forbidden web application firewall security

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, web-application-firewall

i get "403 access forbidden web application firewall security alarm triggered" when i try to update products on virtue mart. i have tried to change different product prices but i still got 403 access forbidden. i have tried logging in with different users but it gives me same error. i also changed log folder and cgi-bin folder permission to 755 but it still gives me 403 access forbidden web application firewall security alarm triggered error.

![This appears every time i want to update my product prices or when i also try to edit k2 i terms][10]

i don't know what to do anymore, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling your web application firewall in the joomla backend? I am going to guess that your site is running AKeeba Tools which is a common component and this may be running a misconfigured. Start there first. Failing that track down where you web firewall is? It maybe your HTACCESS file is non-standard